# PHP mPDF error of saving the pdf file on the local server

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I'm using mPDF for generating my PDF files.

I want the generated PDF files to be saved on the local server.

When I use `$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'F);`, it says:

> Warning: fopen('filename.pdf'): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:/xampp/htdocs/vendor\mpdf\mpdf\src\Mpdf.php on line 9467

The filepath of the first parameter in `Output()`, is correct. So I don't know what's wrong.
The file permissions are also correct.

Does someone know a solution?

With kind regards,

Comment: What file path? You are simply trying to write to `filename.pdf` which means it is trying to write that file in the directory where the PHP file resides.

Comment: @Dave the filepath is ```../../dir1/dir2/filename.pdf```

Comment: Well that isn't in the code you posted and it is likely that mPDF does not understand the use of `../../` in the directory path. If you use an absolute path does it work.

Comment: No it doesn't. I've tried the following: ```$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/dir1/dir2/filename.pdf'``` and it still gives the same error.